# Is $f(n)=n!$, multiplicative, completely multiplicative, or both?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I do not understand how $f(n)=n!$ is multiplicative or completely multiplicative. I know that if gcd$(m,n)=1$ and $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$, then it is multiplicative. If $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$ is true for all integers, then it is completely multiplicative.

Let's take $2$, and $3$, for example. $f((2)(3)=6)=6!$ which is not equal to $2!3!=f(2)f(3). So it is not completely multiplicative.

Now let's take $2$, and $4$, for example. $f((2)(4)=8)=8!$ which is not equal to $2!4!=f(2)f(4). So it is not multiplicative.

The directions given said it has to be at least one but I think it is neither. Any hint would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: It isn't either. Note that $f(2)\cdot f(3)=12$, and $f(2\cdot3)=720$. And, $\gcd(2,3)=1$.

Comment: "The directions given said it has to be at least one"  *what* directions?  Could you explain *who* says it has to be at least one and why?.....  It's neither.  (no need to do two examples.  $f(6)\ne f(2)f(3)$ is enough to disprove both. For any function it is either neither; just multiplicative but not completely multiplicitive; of both.... It can't be completely multiplicative and not multiplicative.... maybe the text was trying to say that and you misunderstood?)

Comment: It is only multiplicative in special cases when either $m$ or $n = 1$

Comment: There are some terrible teachers out there so it could be that.... but I suspect you misunderstood what "the directions" said.  I imagine they were trying to express that a function can't be just completely multiplicative.  It can be both. Or it can be just multiplicative.  But it can't be just completely multiplicative. (or it could be neither.)

Answer (score 4):

It is neither, as you can tell by observing that $2! 3! \neq 6!.$